# Spring-AOP:@AfterReturning is executed immediately

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, aop, spring-aop

Hi I am using Spring AOP for logging ,I have two following aspects @Before and @AfterReturning Unfortunately both are printing the same response here the expectation is @Before print method input and @AfterReturning print method output.

```
 @Before(value ="execution(* com.abc.xyz.service..*(..))")
    fun logBeforeAllMethods(joinPoint: JoinPoint) {
        log.info("Service Request : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.args))
    }

    @AfterReturning(value="execution(* com.abc.xyz.service..*(..))")
    fun logAfterAllMethods(joinPoint: JoinPoint) {
        log.info("Service Response : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.args))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no surprise that both advice methods print the same if you tell them to. In both cases you say you want to print the method **arguments**. Nowhere are you stating that the **result** ought to be printed. You do that via the optional `returning` parameter in the `@AfterReturning` annotation.

Maybe you want to check the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice-after-returning), there is an example for what you want to do (even available in Kotlin!).

```kotlin
@Aspect
class AfterReturningExample {
  @AfterReturning(
    pointcut = "com.xyz.myapp.CommonPointcuts.dataAccessOperation()",
    returning = "retVal")
  fun doAccessCheck(retVal: Any) {
      // ...
  }
}
```

Of course you can also bind both the joinpoint and return value to method parameters if you need both in your advice.

Comment: For some reason this is working by on other methods other than controller methods

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What exactly is working and what is not?

Comment: Sorry some of my methods have return type of Mono it it hard to log Mono object

Comment: That is a completely new question and I can see that you already posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64164101/1082681) separately. I answered this question correctly, so before asking follow-up questions, please be so kind as to accept and upvote this one first.